# Updating Stripe checkout_session for new Price API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have some legacy react code for a stripe integration that was working perfectly until the new Price API landed.  Now, not so much.  Here is my checkout_session function that was working:

```
async function createCheckoutSession(req, res) {
  try {
    const cartItems = req.body;
    const line_items = validateCartItems(products, cartItems);

    const origin = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? req.headers.origin : 'http://localhost:3000'

    const params = {
      submit_type: "pay",
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      billing_address_collection: 'auto',
      shipping_address_collection: {
        allowed_countries: ["MY", "US", "CA"]
      },
      line_items,
      success_url: `${origin}/result?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      cancel_url: origin,
      mode: 'payment'
    }

    const checkoutSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(params);

    res.status(200).json(checkoutSession)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: error.message });
  }
}
```

And now I get this 500 error returned from Stripe...

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or `line_items.images` in this API version. Please use `line_items.price` or `line_items.price_data`. Please see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices for more information."
}
```

From the docs I see that line_items.price, or line_items.price_data is required.  Don't really understand how that is relevant or how to use these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `line_items` array to this:

```
line_items: [
  {
    price_data: {
      currency: _currency,
      product_data: {
        name: _product_name,
      },
      unit_amount: _amount,
    },
    quantity: _quantity,
  },
],
```

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#redirect-customers

The arguments you're using were removed in API version 2022-08-01:
https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01
Technically, you could make your current code work by hardsetting the api_version to something older:
https://stripe.com/docs/libraries/set-version
But I'd suggest migrating to the new arguments.